# jQuery UI Draggable snap rulers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, drag-and-drop

I am setting up a drag and drop interface using jquery and jquery-ui. I've got element snapping working, which is nice, but now I'm trying to get elements to snap at a distance, using some sort of automatic temporary guide rulers.

A very good implementation is on the mac version of Powerpoint. Here's a screenshot of a drag in progress:

[image]

Is there some sort of jQuery plugin that exists for this? If there isn't a plugin, is there some easy way to draw lines that would be snap-able? Is there algorithm for dealing with calculating points and working out which lines to create?

Comment: Were you able to find the answer to your question?

Comment: Nope. I think I ended up just aligning everything to a grid.

Answer (score -1):

You could always copy/paste the snap-part of the draggable.js and change some css values. That would be the easiest way to implement it, since the base is already written in jquery-ui.